# ArcGIS Online create button or lookalike "button" in a popup

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, html

In ArcGIS Pro I can create a button that shows in a popup, but as soon as I publish the layer to AGOL the button doesn't show.

[image: This is how it looks like in ArcGis Pro]

Is there a way to create a button that will show in AGOL webapp when I click a feature? if not, is there a way to create a "look-a-like button" ?

Comment: What happens in ArcPro when you click on this button? I think you need to describe what happens for anyone to offer up a sensible solution.

Answer (score 3):

The ArcGIS Online Help documents has a [HTML considerations](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/supported-html.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_6442922BB60E4D94B28EC8EBEE5FC7BB) page containing the list of supported HTML tags and attributes allowed in popups. The button tag is not on the list and will be filtered out.